# In UWP show selected item in Flex layout for Xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am showing a list in FlexLayout by BindableLayout. I want to show some background color when someone selected an item. It seems really difficult in UWP.

```
  <FlexLayout x:Name="FlexTypes" Wrap="Wrap" Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

                                                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <StackLayout HeightRequest="120" WidthRequest="150">
                                                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Page}, Path=BindingContext.AddItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                                                <Frame Margin="5" Padding="0" CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="#f1f5fb" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                                                                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                                                                        <Frame BackgroundColor="#ffffff" Padding="0" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="50" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="20">
                                                                            <Label Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='₹ {0:N}'}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                                                                        </Frame>
                                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                                </Frame>
                                                            </StackLayout>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am showing a list in FlexLayout by BindableLayout. I want to show some background color when someone selected an item.

For your requirement, we suggest handle it within `TapGestureRecognizer`  `Tapped` event and make a previous value to record clicked item. Then set it background color as default when next item click. For more please refer the following sample code.

```
private Layout previous;
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (previous != null)
    {
        previous.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
    }
    var stacklayout = sender as Layout;         
    stacklayout.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;          
    previous = stacklayout;
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<FlexLayout
    x:Name="FlexTypes"
    Margin="0"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    Wrap="Wrap">
    <BindableLayout.ItemsSource>

        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>1</x:String>
            <x:String>2</x:String>
            <x:String>3</x:String>
            <x:String>4</x:String>
            <x:String>5</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </BindableLayout.ItemsSource>
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout HeightRequest="120" WidthRequest="150">
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <Label Text="{Binding}" />
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</FlexLayout>
```

Comment: Great idea. Thanks